# Div arrangement in last row

Tags: angularjs

I have to repeat `span` in a batch of four in each row and size of parent `div` is fixed.

```
A B C D
E F G H
I J K L
```

If there are less than four `span` in last row, then div should look something like this -

```
A B C D
E F G H
I J K L
M N

A B C D
E F G H
I J K L
M N O
```

Current I am getting this output, using the code in the link -

```
A B C D
E F G H
I J K L
M     N

A B C D
E F G H
I J K L
M  N  O
```

I am using flex. Using `justify-content: center;` in not working. 
Here is what I am doing http://jsfiddle.net/h8to34ux/341/

```js
angular.module('app', [])

.controller('FrameController', ['$injector', function($injector) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.alphabets =['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j']

}]);

setTimeout(function() {
  angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('body'), ['app']);
});
```

```css
.flex{
  width: 400px;
  flex:1;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: green;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.flex-item{
  width:90px;
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div id="body">
  <div ng-controller="FrameController as vm">
    <div class='flex'>
      <span ng-repeat='alphabet in vm.alphabets' class='flex-item'>{{alphabet}}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please add relevant code into your question?

Answer (score 1):

I changed your css to

```
.flex{
  width: 400px;
  display: block;
  float:left;
  background-color: green;
}
.flex-item{
  width:25%;
  background-color: red;
  float:left;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Hope it helps http://jsfiddle.net/h8to34ux/347/

Comment: I can see in jsfiddle that I have pasted...abcd..then efgh...then jk in left...what is not workng?

Comment: abcd..then efgh...then jk are in one line. That's not what I expected. It should be in three lines.

Comment: I saw width set to 5% in jsfiddle.....Above I had pasted 25%...may be thats not saved in jsfiddle...either try this http://jsfiddle.net/h8to34ux/362/ if it is still 5%...just paste my above css in the stylesheet